# Restructuring dataset with seveal identical IDs in different rows

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataset with IDs listed in column 1 and then diagnosis in column 2, cause in column 3 and so on. For IDs with several diagnosis these are listed as one row per diagnosis so the same ID with have several rows. I would like to have everything as one row per ID and the several diagnosis as columns. Is this possible?

My data look somethign like this:

```
ID diagnosis cause_of_diagnosis
1   A  A
1   B  B
1   C  C
2   A  A
3   A  A
3   B  B
3   C  C
```

I would like the data to end up looking something like:

```
ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 cause_of_diagnosis_1 cause_of_diagnosis_2 cause_of_diagnosis_3
 1  A  B  C  A  B  C
 2  A  -  -  A  -  -
 3  A  B  C  A  B  C
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to reshape the data. Use `gather` to get data in long format, `group_by` `ID` and `key` to create a new column name for every "diagnosis" and "cause_of_diagnosis" and `spread` the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, key) %>%
  mutate(key1 = paste(key, row_number(), sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  spread(key1, value)

#     ID cause_of_diagnosis_1 cause_of_diagnosis_2 cause_of_diagnosis_3 diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3
#  <int> <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#1     1 A                    B                    C                    A           B           C          
#2     2 A                    NA                   NA                   A           NA          NA         
#3     3 A                    B                    C                    A           B           C
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),diagnosis = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
cause_of_diagnosis = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you put any values in for key, key1 and value or do you just run this as is?

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen `key` and `key1` are generated on the fly. Run this as is.

Comment: OK - I'm not sure this is doing exactly what I want then. I'm currently not getting any diagnosis columns - but about 700 different cause of diagnosis columns

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen are you sure there is no diagnosis column in the data? The "diagnosis" column would be at the end since the columns are sorted alphabetically. Store the result of above in `df1` and run `grep("^diagnosis", names(df1))` what do you get ?

Comment: yes, there are diagnosis columns as well, but it looks like there are a few hundred of them - which I'm not quite sure as of why that is

Comment: How many "diagnosis" and "cause_of_diagnosis" columns do you expect ? how many rows are present in your data ?